# Eclipse isn't showing 'New PHP file' even while I'm in the PHP perspective

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt, helios

I use eclipse helios PDT at work and at home . I noticed that on my home installation, eclipse doesn't let me create a new PHP file by right clicking on a folder in the PHP explorer. I have to actually right click=>New and then select other and search for PHP from the dialogbox that shows up. But at work everything is ok and it allows me to just right click=>New and then select PHP file.

I'm in the PHP perspective and I've tried switching back and forth a couple of times as well. I've also run it with the -clean command. It's not a major deal, just an irritant, but I was wondering whether you guys knew how to get it back.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try resetting the PHP perspective (Windows → Reset Perspective). This might fix the problem. Controlling which new files are created in each perspective is under Windows → Customize Perspective, under Shortcuts Tab, under submenu New. Resetting the perspective should return this back to normal.

If that doesn't work, you might try uninstalling and reinstalling PDT.

Comment: nice! Resetting fixed the problem. Didn't know you could reset like that. Thanks for this!